# connect sql server to pentaho

Tags: sql-server, virtualbox, pentaho

I want to make a connection between database `sql server` and `pentaho user console`. Before this I use MS SQL Server 2000. However, I can't make a connection. I also use 1433 as port number for this sql server but when I try to make a connection to Pentaho, I realize that it cannot detect port number 1433. What version of SQL Server I should use? Where I can find a good tutorial to do this connection. For everyone information, my database sql server is in 'VBOX' and pentaho is in local network.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server 2000. But don't use driver from microsoft. You must use driver from http://jtds.sourceforge.net/. For detail information about this driver, read the following article : http://www.dbvis.com/doc/microsoft-sql-server-database-drivers/

Comment: If you don't mind, can you give me the download link to get sql server 2000 that you mention above?

Comment: I'm sorry. What I mean is not a link to get jtds driver but a link to download sql server 2000 if you don't mind

Comment: If you need to install fresh, I suggest you go with SQL 2008 (was going to say 2012 even) or higher. I would not go anywhere near SQL 2000 if I can help it.